# Summing given columns by row in DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame defined by:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id':[1,2,3], 
    'activity':['A1', 'A2', 'A2'], 
    'prep_hours':[None,None,1], 
    'delivery_hours':[10,10,15]})
```

I want to create a column `total_hours` which is the sum of all columns matching the pattern `*_hours`

For the time being, I simply add the columns I want into a new column:

```
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
df['total_hours'] = df['prep_hours'] + df['delivery_hours']
```

But it does not scale easily. For the sake of example, I only have 2 columns called `*_hours` but in the real DataFrame, it contains more than 30 columns that should be added.

Is there a smarter way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) with `like` parameter and `sum`, convert missing values to `0` is not necessary:

```
df["total_hours"] = df.filter(like='_hours').sum(axis=1)
print (df)
   id activity  prep_hours  delivery_hours  total_hours
0   1       A1         NaN              10         10.0
1   2       A2         NaN              10         10.0
2   3       A2         1.0              15         16.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could select a subset of your original dataframe using a list_comprehension and add content horizontally like this:

```
columns = [col for col in df.columns if "_hours" in col]
df["total_hours"] = df[columns].sum(axis=1)
```

If the pattern you are looking for is more complicated you could use regex matching as well :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I accepted the other answer because: 1. it is substantially shorter and @jezrael answered before you. However, I really like your answer because it seems more *reusable* in other contexts.

Comment: No worries! Very nice of you to take the time to comment.